# PHP Exibir somente o resultado mais próximo

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia a todos, não sabia exatamente como colocar o titulo, nem como pesquisar isso.
Tenho um `if else` em PHP que diz que se o resultado não for encontrado de primeira, ele tentará achar um resultado similar, fazendo um array com o texto.
Digamos que para o exemplo citado abaixo minha base tenha algo como `significado palavra sono` e o resultado disso seja `Estado caracterizado por supressão da vigília...`
Neste caso as palavras `da` e `palavra` serão localizadas em outras linhas, porém a linha `significado palavra sono` será a mais localizada com um total de 3 localizações.

Como faço para ranquear isso e exibir somente a linha mais localizada ?

**PHP**

```
$texto = "significado da palavra sono";
$palavras = explode(" ", $texto);
foreach($palavras as $palavra){
    $sql = "SELECT * from dicionario where recebido like '%$palavra%'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<p>[".$palavra."]Resultado similar: ".$row['resultado']."<p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Mais a frente quero tentar implantar algo sobre probabilidade.
Outra pergunta, há uma forma melhor de fazer isso ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você deve usar o `Full-Text Search`, veja em https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve substituir o `LIKE` e utilizar o [`Full-Text Search`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match), neste caso deveria de utilizar como exemplo:

```
mysqli_query($con, '
  SELECT   *, 
           MATCH(recebido) AGAINST ("'.$busca.'") AS relevancia 
  FROM     dicionario 
  WHERE    MATCH(recebido) AGAINST ("'.$busca.'")
  ORDER BY relevancia DESC
');
```

Isso irá obter as linhas que a `$busca` estiver em `recebido` e irá ordenar pelo *grau de precisão*, se assim podemos dizer.

---

Acredito que seja recomendável fazer um `INDEX` de [`FULLTEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) da coluna que irá utilizar este recurso, dessa forma:

```
ALTER TABLE `dicionario`
    ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `recebido_nome_do_index` (`recebido`);
```

Essa inclusive é uma vantagem em relação ao `LIKE` que não utiliza os indexes definidos. ;)

Comment: Eu olhei a documentação e não tinha entendido, ai sai pesquisando kkk, mas sua resposta me esclareceu tudo. Funcionando perfeitamente!! Muito Obrigado.